# what does ((double *)0) do internally in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I want to understand what the compiler does when it encounters this statement and `((double*)0+1)` statement.

Comment: Compile it and see what assembly it generates.

Comment: By the way, this is not a statement, this is an expression.

Answer (score 3):

Since `double *` is a pointer type, it propagates the literal value `0` to the `NULL` pointer, then according to the rules of pointer arithmetic, it adds 1 to its value (therefore numerically, the result will be `NULL + sizeof(double)`).

Comment: I let´s say dislike 0 being promoted to null in this case. And whether access to pointers and the related arithmetic is good or evil is undecideable, I think. It surely is useful if you do it right, and very, very nasty to debug if you do it wrong.

Comment: @TheBlastOne What does it matter if you take `(NULL + sizeof(double)` or `0 + sizeof(double)`? It is a pointer to meaningless garbage no matter what. The problem here is not pointer arithmetic but a programmer who writes code pointing into la-la-land, for reasons unknown.

Comment: @H2CO3: Are you asking for the reason for the down vote because you want to understand it and address the concern or because you want to argue with the voter and/or retaliate?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm asking because I see no apparent reason for it.

Comment: The answers is pedagogically deficient. It uses imprecise language that is not defined even for experts and that will just appear as obtuse jargon to a student. The answer uses “numerically” to distinguish adding a number of bytes to an implementation representation of an address from adding a number of elements to a C model of a pointer. But this term is unexplicative, particularly since the so-called “numerical” value is explained with C-style code, `NULL + sizeof(double)`, rather than a mathematical expression or other explanation of virtual address rather than C pointer.

Comment: Additionally, the use of the term “propagates” is not helpful. In fact, in implementations where `NULL` is not represented with a zero address, the literal value `0` is not propagated to `NULL` at all. Correctly stated, `(double *)` is a cast that causes `0` to be **converted** to a null pointer.

Comment: Furthermore, the question has not been completely answered. There are likely two situations in which somebody would ask this question. One is that they are misusing pointers, in which cause it should be explained to them that the behavior of this expression is not defined by the C standard. Another is that this expression appears in the context of a particular C implementation that makes certain guarantees about the behavior. It is an expression that might appear in certain special code calculate structure offsets or object sizes, especially code internal to a C implementation. For this case…

Comment: … it ought to be explained that such special code requires certain guarantees from the compiler and ought not to be used in normal circumstances.

Comment: In summary, this answer uses inappropriate jargon and does not explain very well.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for your feedback, but don't try to hurt me so hard. SO has taught me to be resistent to high amounts of rudeness and hair splitting.

Comment: @H2CO3: It is not about hair splitting. It is about imagining yourself in the position of the person asking the question and seeing what an answer will look like from their point of view. Words that are correct to a person who already knows the answer are not necessarily helpful to somebody who does not know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing whatsoever... it is casting 0 (by definition, the `NULL` pointer) to a pointer to `double`. Presumably to say something like:

```
double *ptr;
....
ptr = ((double *) 0);
....
ptr = NULL;  /* Idiomatic */
ptr = 0;     /* Also allowed, for lazy fingers */
```

All three asignments above do exactly the same thing.

Unless the pointer value cast is 0, you have to be extra careful not to mess up. Most pointer casts are calling for undefined behaviour, they may "work" with today's compìler on your current machine and blow around your ears in a year's time.